# MaskedEditExtender for international phone number

Tags: asp.net, phone-number, maskededitextender

A page contains ajax `MaskedEditExtender` for international phone number. How do I setup `MaskedEditExtender`?

It can allows me to input phone numbers like **+1(454)123-45-67** or **8(113)123-45** or **132(1)123-45-67**.

The phone number contains the country code, the city code and the phone number, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [MaskedEdit Demonstration](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx).

For format international numbers refer to the following:

[E.123 : Notation for national and international telephone numbers, e-mail addresses and web addresses](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-E.123-200102-I/e)

[Telephone numbers: not as easy as they look](http://www.oneis.co.uk/blog/2008/telephone-numbers)

Comment: I've also seen this demonstration. But it says nothing about international phone number format.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you know any easy solution for my problem?

Comment: @Alex Maslakov: I suggest that you use a preliminary format then tune it over time.

Comment: What does mean preliminary format? Could you provide me an example of the code?

Comment: @Alex Maslakov: The priliminary format is based on your current view of the solution. Your view of the solution is improved over time along with the format ..